# How do browsers store creation/expiration dates in cookies?

Tags: c#, database, cookies, time, browser

How do browsers like Firefox or Chrome store timestamps in cookies?

*Chrome:* [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZnSV.png)

*Firefox:* [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCNJ2.png)

and how can I convert those to TimeStamps in C#?

I tried to parse the number with `DateTime.Parse()` but it doesn't work.

Comment: [DateTimeOffset.FromFileTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromfiletime) -- [DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimemilliseconds) -- [DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimeseconds)

Comment: Why do you think WebBrowsers generate timestamps? Have you considered that it might be the Servers' doing :)